# How to transform Strings from csv to Apache Spark MLlib

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I want to load data from CSV and prepare them to a multiclass classification or Regression MLlib algorithm on Apache Spark in Java. Now my CSV has 3 columns:

```
id,main_user,users
1,bob,"bob,charlie,lee,john"
1,grorge,"george,charlie,smith"
2,harvey,"harvey,marley,bob"
2,smith,"smith,name1,name2"
3,william,"william,charlie,george"
3,.....etc...
```

How do I best transform the strings? column 1 and 2. 
I would appreciate any example.

Comment: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: I need String tansformation, in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find an example in three languages

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tf-idf-hashingtf-and-idf

you have to create the feature vector. "Our feature vectors could then be passed to a learning algorithm."

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, That is right. I found the solution before and it was same as this. Thanks anyway.